# Is there a Pokemon evolution line that fits the Sphinx's riddle?

Tags: pokemon-series

So spake the Sphinx:

[image: The Sphinx riddle]

---

**But is there actually a Pokémon that has four legs, then two legs, then three legs in any of the Pokémon games?**

If not, is there at least a Pokémon that has two, three and four legs in any evolutionary order?

Comment: *[Comments Removed]* - This question has a [Meta Discussion](//meta.arqade.com/q/11535/28182), Please contribute your thoughts there instead.

Answer (score 28):

Given the answer to the original sphinx's riddle, you shouldn't look at this so literally, especially the "three legs" phase. Consider this:

[image: slakoth-evolution-chain]

Slakoth is clearly on all fours, much like a human baby. Vigoroth follows, proudly standing on two as a man in his prime might. Slaking has, however, reverted to a three-limbed stance, just like an elderly man with a cane.

Answer (score 15):

There is not yet any Pokemon who change himself physically or who evolve in such a way that it would answer the Sphinx's Riddle. There is some who are starting with two legs and who have three, then four after evolving (such as Roggenrola and its evolutions), but not in this specific order.

[image]